# Powershell: get user profiles name from windows 7/10

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell

I need to get the list of users profile from multiple workstations. I can fetch the details from the below class.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile
```

Problem is it return system profiles too, such as Network Service, LocalService etc. I need to get the details of the actual user profile, not the system profile.

Below is the command which I am using at the moment but it contains the system generated profiles too.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile |
    Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name UserName -Value { (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($this.Sid)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value } -PassThru |   Out-GridView
```

Any advise on this?

Comment: Take a look at `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | Select-Object LocalPath,SID,Special` and think what you can make of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the
[Win32_UserProfile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ee886409%28v%3Dvs.85%29)
property of:

> **Special**
>
> Data type: boolean
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> Indicates whether the user profile is owned by a special system
>   service. True if the user profile is owned by a system service;
>   otherwise false.

You could use in your command the fragment:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -Filter "Special = 'False'"
```